# How can i specify the specific subview to remove?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, subview, removeall

I am trying to remove the UILabel subview from button, through this code
but this code removes all subviews from button even its current image.
I don't understand that how can i specify only UILabel to remove from button.

```
if (![[UIImage imageNamed:@"box1.png"] isEqual:button.currentImage]) {
     [button.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}
```

Comment: what you want to delete?button image with box1.png?

Comment: no, i want to remove UIlabel from it

Comment: set tag values and based on that remove the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1: You added the label. In that case , set it's tag property and retrieve it with `[button viewWithTag:yourLabelTag];`

Case 2: You want to remove the 'titleLabel' of the `UIButton` ( although I cannot think of a reason for it ) . Just do `[button.titleLabel removeFromSuperview];`

Case 3: You have no tag , no pointer to the label and you want to remove all instances of `UILabel` added to the button:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < button.subviews.count ; i++) //you could use for(UIView *v in button.subviews) but you shouldn't change the array during this kind of enumeration.
{
   UIView *v = [button.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
   if([v isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]])
   {
      [v removeFromSuperview];
      i--;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Best way is set `tag` value to the views and delete the views based on the `tag` values.